# the correct way using middleware in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, express

hey I want to make sure if I use the correct way for **middleware** in my simple express app, I am trying to find the email unique for register
here is my example

```js
const isUnique = (req, res, next) => {
   User.findOne({
      where:{
        email: req.body.email
      }
   })
   .then(getUser => {
        if(getUser){
          next("/userAlreadyExist") // router
          // or can i render to to html? i am using ejs
        } else {
          next()
        }
   })
   .catch(next())
}


app.post('/register', isUnique ,(req, res) => {
    res.send(`thank you for register`)
}
```

I want to make sure the email already exists or no, so I want to pass it on **middleware** first, and get a page for `isUnique`, if the email already in use, I want to redirect it to next router called `'/emailExist'`, and if it success i want to redirect it to router `/success`
can anyone help me if that code wrong or no? just want to make sure :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of options, here are a couple.

1. You can redirect users to specific pages based on whether or not the email exists. Within your `/emailAlreadyExists` and `/registerSuccess` routes you can render whatever templates you want or return some data.

```
const isUnique = (req, res, next) => {
   User.findOne({
      where:{
        email: req.body.email
      }
   })
   .then(getUser => {
        if (getUser) {
            res.redirect('/emailAlreadyExists');
        } else {
            res.redirect('/registerSuccess'); // or just call next()
        }
   })
   .catch(next("DB error"));
}
```

1. Pass along the results of the db query and let your final middleware handle it:

```
const isUnique = (req, res, next) => {
   User.findOne({
      where:{
        email: req.body.email
      }
   })
   .then(getUser => {
        req.user = getUser;
        next();
   })
   .catch(next());
}

app.post('/register', isUnique ,(req, res) => {
    if (req.user) {
        res.send('User already exists');
    } else {
        res.send(`thank you for register`);
    }
}
```

2. You can also create an [error handling middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html):

```
const isUnique = (req, res, next) => {
   User.findOne({
      where:{
        email: req.body.email
      }
   })
   .then(getUser => {
        if(getUser){
          next("Error: user already exists"); // or some other error message/object
        } else {
          next(); // continue to next middleware
        }
   })
   .catch(next("DB error")); // handle errors throw from DB read
}


app.post('/register', isUnique ,(req, res) => {
    res.send(`thank you for register`)
}

/*
    If you call "next" with an argument, Express will skip 
    straight to this error handler route with the argument 
    passed as the "err" parameter
*/

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500).send(`An error occurred: ${err}`);
})
```

Comment: how about if i want to handle the next router if the user already exist ??:D

Comment: can i redirect?

Comment: perfect, let me try it , thank you for explaning :D

Comment: if user not exist  we redirect it to next router, it meant we not usse middle ware ? because we stop it ? so is that best way to call next() for the else ?

Comment: Express middleware are a sequence of functions that process a single request. When you call `next()`, you are handing control over to the next middleware function in the sequence. So in `app.post('/register', isUnique, (req, res) => ...)`, if you call `next()` with no arguments inside `isUnique`, you will pass control into the `(req, res) => ...` function. You can check out the Express [middleware docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router), and if you're still lost try putting print statements in your functions and see what happens